# Content in <p> goes over the div (inserted dynamically with Java)

Tags: html, css, jsp

When I insert text dynamically with java (we are using .jsp), the paragraph gets extended across the border of the div, although it is perfectly fine if I copy paste the text inside. It is not an issue of *white-space*. The other example is what happens if I just manually copy the text in the developer's tools or use a static text.!

[image]

[image]

Comment: string in the above pic has NO spaces although string in the below image has spaces. May be it doesn't get wrapped off because of that ?

Comment: God, how didn't I think of that, that was exactly what the problem was :D Thank a lot

Comment: Do you mind accepting it if I post my comment as answer here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.class
{
  max-width: 100px; /*or whatever*/
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[Reference](http://www.brunildo.org/test/IEbreak-word.html)

Comment: Thanks for helping out, 'word-wrap: break-word' is what did the trick.

Comment: Cool! (BTW: You don't just need to accept an answer, if it didn't worked for you, you don't have to accept it! (Only accept answers how solved your problem AND helped you the most))

Answer (score 2):

Break up the words in your sample text with some spaces or add the following to your style sheet:

```
p {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```